# Fresh install of VS Enterprise 2019 missing AspNetCore and Azure packages

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've just did a fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise on Windows 11. No previous VS installations.

Upon creating a new project (in this instance Azure Functions) I am getting errors that packages such as `AspNetCore`, and `Azure` are not available.

I have the required SDK's installed as can be seen from the image below:

[image: Installed SDK's from Microsoft Visual Studio Installer]

Here is an image showing the errors in the editor:

[image: Missing package errors in Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019]

What I don't understand is I didn't have this issue when I was running Visual Studio Community edition on Windows 10. I did a fresh install yesterday.

I also noticed that under `Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager` Settings I only have an offline source listed. Should there be a URL to pull packages online?

I'm not sure how to solve this. I've did a repair, and a fresh installation and I still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was no online package source defined for nuget.

First, head to `Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings`. Click the `Package Sources` tab.

Press the green `+` button to add a new source. Enter the following settings:

- Name: `nuget.org`
- Source: `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Like so ...

[image: Nuget package sources dialog]

If like me you have a project open that's missing packages simply hit the build button and Visual Studio will restore the missing packages.